# error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.66: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: 18.04

I have installed VISIT but when I try to launch its GUI it gives this error. error while loading shared libraries: libicui18n.so.66: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory Any idea how to resolve the issue on Ubuntu 18.04.6

Comment: Which version of VISIT did you install, and how exactly? Please [edit] your question to provide details.

Comment: How did you "install VISIT"?

Comment: I installed visit from source code from the link https://visit-dav.github.io/visit-website/releases-as-tables/ and then followed the instructions on the install readme. The version is 3.2.0

Comment: Did you take care to install the Ubuntu [18](https://github.com/visit-dav/visit/releases/download/v3.2.2/visit3_2_2.linux-x86_64-ubuntu18.tar.gz) version?

Comment: Yes. I did take care of that